# Pass each file obtained from a command to another command as a parameter

Tags: linux, bash

I am using the following line to take a pdf and split it:

```
pdfseparate -f 14 -l 23 ALF.SS.0.pdf "${FILE}"-%d.pdf
```

Now I want for each file produced, to run several commands like this:

```
pdfcrop --margins '-30 0 -385 0' outputOfpdfSeparate outputOfpdfSeparate-1stCol.pdf
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to do this:

1. With a single loop, for each file created by pdfseparate, if I manage to "know" what is the name of the file, I could pass it to pdfcrop and done. But since it is using %d, I do not know how to handle this "new name" in which each file has a new number. I know how to do this in Java but here I do not see it so clear.
2. Using pipes. I think I have the same issue since if I do

   `pdfseparate [options] | pdfcrops inputfile outputfile`,

   I do not know how to "use" the name of inputfile. I am sure it is easy but I dont see it.
3. Using xargs. I am studying this command since it is new for me.
4. Using exec. I am under the impression this is not necessary but maybe I am wrong since it's been a long while since I last used exec.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `xargs` in parallel. It is the best we in terms of speed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs`. It is the best way in terms of speed.

I usually use it for converting a lot of `.mp4` file to `.mp3`.

Doing this conversion one-by-one not only is tedious but also takes a long time. Therefore you can use the **auto parallel** mechanism with the help of `-P 0` option in `xargs`

for example if I had 10 `.mp4` files I would do this:

```
ls *.mp4 | xargs -I xxx -P 0 ffmpeg -i xxx xxx.mp3
```

After running this line; 10 `ffmpet` commands are running simultaneously.
The other way to do this is storing a list of `.mp4` file in a text file like this:

```
ls *.mp4 > list-mp4
```

then:

```
 xargs -I xxx -P 0 ffmpeg -i xxx xxx.mp3 < list-mp4
```

Or may you have access to GNU-parallel. Thus you can:

```
parallel ffmpeg -i {} {}.mp3 ::: *.mp4
```

---

Now for your case; if you want to use these (= `xargs` or `parallel`) or your own command, you should notice that your **first command** should send its output to `stdout`. Because the **second command** is going to read its `stdin` from the `stdout` of the **first command** and [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) does this for your.

Thus when you can use `pipe` == `|` with your: `pdfseparate` than it sends its output to `stdout`. If it does/can NOT, then the right-side of the `pipe` == the **second command** does nothing and vice versa: the **second command** should/can read its `stdin` from incoming `stdout`.

For example

```
ls *.txt |  echo {}
```

here `echo` does not read any incoming `stdout` from the `ls` command and just prints `{}`

Eventually, your `pdfseparate` should send to `stdout`. Then `xargs` store it in `-I anything-your-like` and then call your **second command**

Therefor:

```
pdfseparate options... | xargs -I ABC -P 0 your-second-command+its-options ABC
```

**NOTE-1** that `xargs` stores the given `stdout` line-by-line in `ABC` and you pass this to your **second command** as its input

**NOTE-2** you do not have to use `-P 0` at all. It is just for speeding up the executing time. You can omit it but your **second command** are synchronized per incoming line.

Answer (score 0):

pdfseparate does not output the files it created, thus you have to use "ls" command to get the filelist, you want to operate on.
    # separate the pdfs 
    pdfseparate -f 14 -l 23 ALF.SS.0.pdf "${FILE}"-%d.pdf

```
# operate on the just created files, assumes that a "FILE" variable is set, which might not be the case
for i in $(ls "${FILE}-*.pdf"); do pdfcrop --margins '-30 0 -385 0' $i; done;

# assuming that FILE variable in your case would match ALF.SS.0-[0-9]*.pdf, you'd use this:
for i in $(ls ALF.SS.0-[0-9]*.pdf); do pdfcrop --margins '-30 0 -385 0' $i; done;
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the help. But I am sorry because I might explained myself poorly: the outputOfpdfSeparate parameter of the second command, pdfcrop, has to be the whatever file the pdfseparates command outputs. So how should I change that parameter name?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the answer.

Comment: Hey, any luck with the snippet?

Comment: Hi, I am very sorry for not answering sooner. Unfortunately not, I wasn't able to do it this way so I simply did first one operation then the other, I am 99% sure it was my own fault but I did not manage to get it this way.